# How do I keep two softbodies in the same position?

Tags: animation, coordinates, soft-body

I have two softbody cubes, one is smaller than the other. They are both aflling at the same speed, but the problem is that when the bigger cube lands, the smaller cube goes all the way down. Is there a way to keep both cubes' position the same?

[image]

I want them to be in the same position.

[blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/0c554a7581c54a1aa926f4998570835a)

Comment: I will be sleeping when this question is answered, I will accept any answers in the morning.. thanks :)

Comment: You could try adding a second collision floor so that the middle softbody lands in the right height you want. Just make sure to change the collision layer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more detail and/or screenshots to illustrate the setup and situation without requiring someone to download and open the Blend file.

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your .blend file is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. Do you want the small cube to NOT impact the collision cube? To stay at the centre of the larger, softbody cube while the larger cube does it's impact? Do you want the smaller cube to react as though it hit something? Or just wobble like it's trapped inside the larger cube?

Comment: Sorry, I am going to edit my question.

Comment: @NascentSpace I don't understand

Comment: @Psyonic 
> Or just wobble like it's trapped inside the larger cube? 
yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Assign all verts in BigCube to a vertex group.  Give SmallCube a copy location constraint, targeting BigCube and referencing this vertex group.  Give SmallCube a healthy Goal value (or group).
2. Join BigCube and SmallCube into a single object.  Create edges (only) between BigCube and SmallCube to create forces between the two.  These will act as any other soft body edges, seeking to maintain their length (and possibly, with positive soft body bending values, lengths to neighbor verts), causing SmallCube to prefer to float inside of BigCube rather than fall completely to the ground.

Comment: For some reason, only smallcube falls when i do the second option, and I don't know how to do what you said in the first one.

Comment: nevermind, I got it to work by clearing the bake cache, thanks!